# Lock cells after data entry NO VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

is there a way to lock cells after a user enters data on the adjacent cell without using VBA?

for example
the user enters "Y" on B1 and a time stamp generates on B2 I need B1 & B2 to lock right after and require a password for them to be edited.

Answer (score 3):

The **short answer** is: No

The **Long answer** is: Still No, but with the following explanation.

Native Formulas only effect the cells in which they are placed and only the values.

These formulas are live as in, any formula that will place todays date on completion of another cell will change with each calculation of Excel as TODAY() and NOW() are volatile.  You cannot make them stay stagnate (Using circular references will not survive the restart).

Formulas, also, cannot change the format or locked setting of cells, even the ones in which they are placed.  Nor can they protect and unprotect a sheet.

The only way to accomplish this is through vba in a [Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event, where the code triggers on changes to the sheet.

Comment: I have bookmarked this long answer, very helpful indeed =)